# JTable Question

Tags: java

I just want to ask how can I populate my Jtable using Jlist. I have created a JList using eclipse and I want to add the data to another class with a JTable. When I click the add button on the JList class the data on JList should be added on the Jtable.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Create an implementation of `AbstractTableModel` and implement the following methods:

```
  public int getColumnCount();

  public int getRowCount();

  public String getColumnName(int column);

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column);
```

Needless to say, your implementation of `AbstractTableModel` will take a reference to the JList in its constructor.

Finally autopopulate the table as follows:

```
JTable tab = new JTable(new MyAbstractTableModel(myJList));
```

See the followimg links for more details:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TableModelExample.htm

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am having a bit problem on it, I tried what you suggest and I am still having problem on getting the JList. My JList is on another class.

`abstract class Table extends AbstractTableModel {
  
  public abstract int getColumnCount();

    public abstract int getRowCount();

    public abstract String getColumnName(int column);

    public abstract Object getValueAt(int row, int column);
    
    JTable tab = new JTable((TableModel) new JTable (allList));
 }
}
`

I am having a problem on allList which is my List. Sorry for asking so much I am new on Java.

Comment: You should post this code in another question or update this question with this code, but the problems I see here are: Your class that implements AbstractTableModel should not itself be abstract. You actually need to implement those abstract methods. You should be creating an instance of your Table class with your list, allList, not an instance of JTable. Then create the JTable with your Table.

Comment: Why should the model know about the view. That's usually a bad design, consider what happens if you want to use the same model for two different views, you'd have problems. The view should know about the model, not the other way around.

Comment: As I said in the answer, your implementation of AbstractTableModel must be concrete and not abstract by itself. Checkout the second link that I posted, that contains a running example.